# Unable to predict values for future dates

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series, predict, forecast

I am trying to predict future values in a dataframe. Since new dates do not exist I am unable to predict values using below command:
df['forecast'] = results.predict(start='2017-08-16', end='2017-08-22')

Dataset

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

It will create new 10 Days and added into `date` column in `df`.

Code-

```
df = df.reindex(df.date.union(pd.date_range(df.date.max(),periods=10)))
```

If your index is datetime.index , then you can use below code.

```
df = df.reindex(df.index.union(pd.date_range(df.index.max(),periods=10)))
```

Ref link- [Generate Dates for next 10 Weekdays in Dataframe from the after last date in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72078721/generate-dates-for-next-10-weekdays-in-dataframe-from-the-after-last-date-in-dat)

Comment: Thank you!! It turned out I had some duplicate values in index so I resampled it and it worked. Since I am new to this subject, will use your method too to get a better understanding. :)